# How can I change the ports used by built-in GNOME remote desktop for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm new to the Ubuntu world and would appreciate some information regarding the built-in remote desktop features.
Unfortunately, my institution restricts the use of certain port numbers, such as 3389 and 5900, which are used for RDP and VNC connections by default.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the default port numbers to bypass these restrictions.
Any advice or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If your institution permits SSH, you might want to consider keeping the default port(s), but tunnelling the traffic over an SSH connection