# How can I change RDP port number in gnome-remote-desktop in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, rdp

In Ubuntu 22.04 and later, support GUI remote control via built-in gnome-remote-desktop in RDP protocol.

I found similar question but cannot get valuable answer.

[How can I change the ports used by built-in GNOME remote desktop for Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459177/how-can-i-change-the-ports-used-by-built-in-gnome-remote-desktop-for-ubuntu-22-0)

Default port of rep is 3389. However, I should change the port number due to the institution's security policy.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** While not a complete answer, you may want to review the following discussion, as it's relevant: https://askubuntu.com/q/1459177/32664.

Comment: Are you the _same_ person that asked the same question mentioned above by @richbl?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the option of tunnelling the traffic over an SSH connection as suggested in the comments, you can try to change the value of `port=3389` in file `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`. I haven't tested that, but it is should work.

After that, you should restart the service with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart xrdp
```

Also, if you have a firewall, do not forget to update the firewall rules to allow inbound connections to the new port.